# When flying with Volaris, what difference does it make between flying to TIJ or TJX?

Tags: airports, mexico, tij, volaris, tijuana

In searching flights with Volaris, the destinations offered include "Tijuana TIJ" and "Tijuana Cross-Border Xpress TJX".  What is the difference between these?

Screenshot example:

[image]

Comment: I could bur should not have to, an image on Stack Exchange should support the text, not replace it.

Comment: It is in the rules, you have been told before.

Comment: @Willeke my image supports the text, not replace it

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Screen readers can't read the text in an image.  And I have seen many comments about people on various SEs who do use screen readers.

Comment: I edited to make the question text more self-contained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TJX [includes](https://cms.volaris.com/globalassets/pdfs/eng/cbx-terms-and-conditions.pdf) the CBX charges while TIJ does not.

From linked PDF

> When booking a flight to Tijuana-Cross Border Express TJX, the CBX
> service (closed pedestrian bridge that spans the border  between the
> United States of America and the United Mexican States) will be added
> automatically in the passenger's final reservation.
> The boarding pass can  be used to board the flight and to enter the
> Cross Border Xpress, the client must consult the documents required to
> enter at the  [www.crossborderspress.com](http://www.crossborderspress.com) link. In case you have not
> selected the Tijuana-Cross Border Express TJX station, the CBX service
> can be purchased independently if the selected route is from / to
> Tijuana.

Comment: Did you mean www.crossborderxpress.com link?